# Найти,из введенных строк, строку с максимальной и минимальной длинной

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, поиск

Здравствуйте есть вот такое задание:

**Пользователь вводит последовательность строк, состоящих из слов и чисел, разделенных
пробелами. Признак конца последовательности – пустая строка. Вывести самые короткие и
самые длинные слова в строке**

Код ниже.Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как реализовать вывод нескольких строк с максимальной и минимальной длинной(т.е. если в массив входит несколько строк с одинаково короткой или одинаково длинной длиной он вывел их всех,а не только последнюю.)
Прошу прощения за говнокод и за глупую просьбу,если она таковой является.Спасибо.

```html
<script>
  function readStrings(obj) {
    var str = ' ';
    while (true) {
      str = prompt("Введите строку текста (слова через пробел)", "");
      if (str == '') break;
      var words = str.split(' ');
      for (var i in words)
        if (words[i] != 0) obj.push(words[i]);
    }
  }
  text = [];
  readStrings(text);
  var minnum = text[0].length;

  for (i = 0; i <= text.length - 1; i++) {
    if (text[i].length <= minnum) {
      var min = text[i];
      minnum = text[i].length;
    }
  }
  var maxnum = text[0].length;
  for (j = 0; j <= text.length - 1; j++) {
    if (text[j].length >= maxnum) {
      var max = text[j];
      maxnum = text[j].length;
    }
  }
  document.write(min + '<br>' + text + '<br>' + max)
</script>
```

Comment: В формулировке сделан акцент на различии между словами и числами. Значит ли это, что, например, для строки "абв 1 гдежз 1234567 ийкл" должны быть выведены "абв" и "гдежз"?

Comment: Простите,что поздно ответил(очень поздно).На самом деле я сам до конца не понял,но у меня приняли задание при котором ,в случае если есть такая строка - " 123 авб гджз 456",выводит сначала цифры,потом слова

Comment: Не вполне ясно, как это сочетается с приведенной формулировкой задания, но что приняли — это уже хорошо. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это несложно сделать, и, думаю, вариантов существует множество.
Можете попробовать сделать вот так. Это достаточно многословный вариант, и на самом деле его можно немного уменьшить, но в таком виде, мне кажется, вам будет проще понять, что, когда и зачем мы делаем:

```js
function readStrings() {
  const words = []

  while (true) {
    const str = prompt("Введите строку текста (слова через пробел)", "")
    if (str == "") {
      break
    }

    words.push(...str.split(" "))
  }

  return words
}

// получаем список всех слов
const words = readStrings()

// группируем слова в объект, где ключ - длина слова,
// а значение - массив слов с этой длиной
const wordsByLegth = words.reduce((acc, v) => {
  if (!acc[v.length]) {
    acc[v.length] = []
  }

  acc[v.length].push(v)

  return acc
}, {})

// получаем массив всех длин
const keysLength = Object.keys(wordsByLegth).map(v => Number(v))

// получаем минимальную и максимальную длины
const min = Math.min(...keysLength)
const max = Math.max(...keysLength)

// выводим все слова, самые короткие и самые длинные
console.log("Все слова:", words.join(", "))
console.log("Самые короткие слова:", wordsByLegth[min].join(", "))
console.log("Самые длинные слова:", wordsByLegth[max].join(", "))
```